# ImageButtons on ImageView [Android]

Tags: android, android-layout, button, xamarin, imageview

I want to put ImageButtons on ImageView: [image]
I tried to do this with linear layout but always buttons appearing under imageview. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your relevant code so we can see what order you are building the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's were FrameLayout comes in it has the ability of putting a view on top of another. So whenever you add one child to the frame layout the next child will appear on top of the previous one if present.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/imageview"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_height="250px"
    android:layout_width="250px"/>

  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/widget43"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="100px"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
  <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/album_icon" />
 <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/ImageButton02"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/album_icon"
  />
 <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/ImageButton03"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/album_icon"
  />
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/album_icon"
   />

  </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

Frame layout childrens layout gravity and gravity can also customized so for this case is a linear layour with horizontal orientation but the first is image view!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in xml. I hope it helps (See screenshot at the bottom)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pc"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
        android:src="@drawable/phone"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/phone"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/phone"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and align the ImageButtons to the ImageView [bottom](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_BOTTOM).

Answer (score 0):

use FrameLayout

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

it's made so the first child is under the second child and so on

you can put an imageview [matchparent,matchparent]
and a linearlayout under it containing your imagebuttons

both in the Framelayout

here's a better example:

http://abhiandroid.com/ui/framelayout